# D3 scale with string domain in V4

Tags: d3.js, range, scale

I'd like to create a scale with string domain:

```
var scale = d3.scaleXXX().domain(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]).range([0, width]);
```

in order to have this method:

```
scale(domain: string): number
```

to draw lines this conversion method like this:

```
svgNode.append('line')
    .attr('x1', (domain) => Math.round(scale(domain)))
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', (domain) => Math.round(scale(domain)))
    .attr('y2', height);
```

I do not find the good scale type and method to set the domain, the range and get the right conversion method.

May you help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me (correct me if I'm wrong) that that the issue is not having a *"string"* domain (whatever it is), but a domain with a **categorical** variable being mapped to a **quantitative** range.

In that case, the adequate scale is a [point scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scalePoint). According to the docs,

> Unlike continuous scales, ordinal scales have a discrete domain and range [...] Point scales are a variant of band scales with the bandwidth fixed to zero. Point scales are typically used for scatterplots with an ordinal or categorical dimension.

Here is a demo, loosely based on your snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(data)
  .range([20, 280]);
var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", 120)
  .attr("x1", d => scale(d))
  .attr("x2", d => scale(d))
  .style("stroke", d => color(d))
  .style("stroke-width", 2);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,130)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted and meant.
I tried to map categorical variable to a quantitative range using scaleOrdinal while the working solution is to use a scalePoint companion.